# Записать символы в файл в обратном порядке

Tags: c, файлы

С клавиатуры вводятся символы, необходимо получить файл с этими символами, записанными в обратном порядке (например, при вводе `12134` в файл нужно записать `43121`)

Нельзя использовать массивы (количество символов может быть очень велико) и функцию `fseek()`

Comment: записывать каждый символ в новый файл, потом собрать их в обратном порядке :)

Comment: Нехорошо выкладывать сюда свои домашние задания. Для начала стоило бы попробовать что-то сделать самостоятельно. А уже затем, при возникновении конкретных трудностей, задавать вопрос.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это домашнее задание без попыток решить его самостоятельно

Comment: В вопросах, касающихся учебных заданий, правильно описывать свои попытки и то, что в них не получилось. Выкладывание только формулировки задания не приветствуется сообществом.

Comment: @PashaPash Некоторые домашние задания интересны сами по себе. Ответ на них может принести пользу не только автору вопроса. Кроме того, всегда можно ответить так, что как раз автору, желающему получить готовое решение, ответ ничего не даст.

Comment: @Shamov основное назначение SO - организация знаний. а не развлечение скучающих толп и не троллинг школьников. нельзя использовать `fseek()` - в топку, как вопрос с искусственными ограничениями, ответ на который никому ничего не даст.

Comment: @PashaPash Искусственные ограничения типичны для учебных заданий. Так что факт их наличия не выводит вопрос за рамки соответствующего тега, который разрешён.

Comment: @Shamov тег не может быть разрешенным или нет. это просто тэг. SO предназначен для поиска решения технических проблем. а полное отсутствие самостоятельных попыток решить задачу - это **не техническая проблема**. Общая политика по поводу "решите за меня" высказана в http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, не вижу смысла в каждом закрытом вопросе ее обсуждать.

Comment: @Shamov причем основная цель - запрета на "решите за меня" - это не попытка "запретить интересные задачи". а попытка пресечь волну "там на сайте лабы нахаляву делают". если хотите высказаться по поводу написания чужих лаб - сделайте это в http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: @PashaPash Про лабы нахаляву никто не говорит. Автора вопроса вообще можно исключить из уравнения. Его проблема действительно не техническая. Но речь-то идёт о накоплении базы знаний. Чтобы люди могли находить решения интересных задач, должна быть возможность их добавлять. Данный вопрос именно такой. Причём интересным его делает именно ограничение на использование `fseek()`. Я не против того, чтобы закрывать тупые вопросы. Но если вопрос интересный, то это гораздо важнее, чем то, что автор может получить незаслуженную выгоду. Волну халявщиков можно пресечь, закрывая лишь тупые вопросы.

Comment: @Shamov данный вопрос - обычное задание по программухе, которое тупо скопипащено из задачника. Хотите интересных задач - возьмите учебник и решайте. Дело не в награде, дело в том, что вы поощеряете автора постить сюда задачи из учебника. Если этот вопрос переоткроют - я заведу виртуала, и скопипащу сюда пачку задач из любого учебника. Посмотрим как весело будет разгребать этот мусор.

Comment: @Shamov - хотите видеть тут задачи из учебников - выскажитесь на мете.

Comment: @PashaPash Я хочу видеть тут решения интересных задач. Из учебников эти задачи или нет - мне не важно.

Comment: @Shamov а я не хочу видеть здесь задачи. и?. сайт создан для решения реально существующих технических проблем. Об этом явно сказано в on-topic. Хотите "решебник" на русском - идите на Area 51 и там его пропихивайте.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23314/discussion-between-pashapash-and-shamov).

Answer (score 1):

Основная идея здесь - использовать рекурсию вместо цикла для чтения и записи символов. Ведь для того, чтобы вывести N чисел в порядке, обратном чтению, нужно сначала вывести N-1 последнее число в обратном порядке, а затем - первое. Продолжая аналогию, доходим до N = 1, в этом случае просто выводим число.

В псевдокоде идея выглядит так:

```
функция вывести_N_чисел_в_обратном_порядке(N)
    x = прочитать_число()
    если N > 1
        вывести_N_чисел_в_обратном_порядке(N - 1)
    вывести_число(x)
```

Основной трюк здесь - хранение прочитанных чисел в стеке вызовов, что позволяет, во-первых, обойтись без явного объявления массива, а во-вторых, вытаскивать числа в порядке, обратном записи.

Comment: Цитата из задачки: "количество символов может быть очень велико".

Comment: @Athari но и не сказано, как программа должна узнать, что пора остановиться. Данный пример для случая, когда программа должна остановиться через N символов. N вполне может быть очень велико

Comment: @Athari Если условие, что программа должна остановиться после какого-то спец. символа, то достаточно поменять условие в `ЕСЛИ`

Comment: А если нет - можно читать файл 2 раза: превый - чтобы определить его длину, второй - собственно, для вывода символов. Или (в порядке бреда) прочитать файл, определив его длину, затем N раз читать его до i-го симвлоа и выводить. Медленно, зато вообще без дополнительной памяти, даже в виде стека.

Comment: Существует решение без рекурсии.

Comment: Я про то, что стек обычно не резиновый, "великое количество символов" он не выдержит.

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее интересным в данной задаче является вопрос о том, как вставить символ в начало файла, не используя при этом дополнительной памяти и временных файлов, а также не перемещаясь по файлу произвольным образом.

Существует один трюк, который позволяет это сделать. Соответствующая функция могла бы выглядеть вот так.

```
void prepend(char ch, const char* filename) {
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r+");
    if (!fp) fp = fopen(filename, "w+");

    int buf;
    while ((buf = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        ungetc(buf, fp);
        fputc(ch, fp);
        ch = (char)buf;
    }
    fputc(ch, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно поздний ответ, но попробуйте вот так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
    char str[20];       //создаем массив строки
    int i;              //переменная счетчик
    puts("Vvedite stroku\n");        //выводим на экран просьбу создания              строки
    gets(str);                       //сохраняем в массив строку
    for (i=0; str[i]!='\0'; i++);    //цикл выводит строку в прямом порядке
    printf("\n%s sodergit %d simvolov \n", str, i);
    for (str[i]='\0'; i>=0; i--)     //цикл выводит строку в обратном порядке
        printf("%c\n", str[i]);


}
```